# Sequential and co-executing programs

Tags: batch-file, pipe, sequential

Are the commands contained in a batch file an example of a sequential program? Then what are co-executing programs? Can we say that clubbing output of one program to be input to another program using UNIX pipe is an example of co-executing programs?

Comment: Piping output from one command to the input of another is sequential. One step occurs after the previous one ends (the program receiving the output of the other can't execute until the other program is done). That being said, I believe you can write batch scripts in a way that they will multithread (run concurrent/co-executing) certain operations. Piping, I believe, isn't one of those methods though.

Comment: Reworded for clarity, Touched up grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Piping commands is done on a line by line basis (both programs alternativly run). However at the end of the process it appears sequential.

Windows has Job Objects, which are collections of processes. One crash, they all crash in sympathy.

You need to say what your goal is, rather than asking questions about how some vague idea might help you.